# jQuery / AJAX - re-initialize functions after AJAX call for new items only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using 3 jQuery plugins on my page. They all work fine until I make an AJAX call and load in new elements. If I simply re-initialize these plugins, then it causes chaos on the page due to some being initialized multiple times. I just want to initialize them for the new items. Can anyone assist with this?

I am using Hover Caption (http://ryun.github.io/HCaptions/), (http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs) and a countdown (http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    // mouseover
    $('.hcaption').hcaptions({effect: "fade"});
    //animate tiles
    $(".live-tile").liveTile({pauseOnHover: true});

    function loadMoreItems(getQuery, page) {
        //reset infinate scroll somehow
        /*jQuery.ias({
            //container: '#container'
        });
        //setTimeout("jQuery.ias({container: '#container'})",1000);*/
        //load items
        $.get(getQuery, null, function(data) {
        var container = $(data).find('#container');
        $( container ).find( '.hcaption' ).hcaptions({effect: "fade"});
        //remove any repeated discounts
        $(".element").each(function() { 
            var discount_id = "#" + this.id;
            //$('.hcaption').hcaptions({effect: "fade"});
        });
        if (container) {
            var newItemsHTML = "";
            newItemsHTML = $(container).html();
            var $newItems = $(newItemsHTML);
            $container.isotope('insert', $newItems, true);
        }
    }, 'html');
}
}
```

**EDIT**
After the suggestion below, I've managed to add a class to elements when they are first loaded.  I am now struggling to add the .hcaptions({effect: "fade"}) to them on filter. None of the below work.

```
                     //$('.hcaption').hcaptions({effect: "fade"});
                    //$(container).find('.hcaption').not("activated").hcaptions({effect: "fade"});
                     /*$(container).find('.hcaption').not("activated").hcaptions({effect: "fade"}).addClass("activated");
                     $(container).find('.hcaption').not("activated");*/
```

Comment: check for each plugin if some data are been added to elements {$.data()} or specific class and filter using it

Comment: I really struggle with the syntax of JQuery.  Can you provide example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to add a class like `alreadyActivated` on the elements you initialize with the plugins, and do your filter only on items which don't have this class :

```
$('.hcaption').hcaptions({effect: "fade"}).addClass("alreadyActivated");
$(".live-tile").liveTile({pauseOnHover: true}).addClass("alreadyActivated");

//target only elements not activated, and then add the class
$('.hcaption').not("alreadyActivated").hcaptions({effect: "fade"}).addClass("alreadyActivated");
```

Comment: Thats sounds great, although it doesn't appear to be adding the class.  Is the syntax correct?  Many thanks

Comment: OK, Ive got it to add the class by adding two separate lines:                 $('.hcaption').addClass("alreadyActivated");
$('.hcaption').hcaptions({effect: "fade"}); but am now struggling with the 2nd part.

Comment: What the problem ? Try just `$('.hcaption').not("alreadyActivated").hcaptions({effect: "fade"});`. PS : Have you try my solution on your other question ?